# PHP date format "2015-12-31T13:54:59.123+05:30"

Tags: php, datetime, format

What would be the date format in php to get date like this 
`2015-12-31T13:54:59.123+05:30`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: its c - The ISO-8601 date (e.g. 2013-05-05T16:34:42+00:00) format, refer this link for more reference, http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Comment: Normal dates in PHP do not handle micro/milliseconds. If you want them, you're going to have to use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

Comment: Niranjan, I have already checked out 'C' on php.net but this is not exactly what I am looking for but yes its close to it.

Comment: For those who down voted, please let me know Why you down voted so that I can improvise my question next time . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet to get the current date:

```
<?php
$microTime = explode(" ",microtime());
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date=date('Y-m-d:H:i:s');
$timeZone=date('P');
echo $date.substr((string)$microTime[0],1,4).$timeZone;
```

If you wish to enter a date of your choice use the following code.

```
<?php
$microTime = explode(" ",microtime());
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$new=date(DATE_ATOM,mktime(13,54,59,12,31,2015));
$date=date('Y-m-d:H:i:s',strtotime($new));
$timeZone=date('P');
echo $date.substr((string)$microTime[0],1,4).$timeZone;
```

Comment: Hi Anurag, thanks for the code ... but its resulting in `2015-10-06:08:40:17.865+05:30`

Comment: Hi, I have modified the code for user entered date. Have a look